# iOS app gets stuck on Launch Image on iOs 10.3

Tags: storyboard, ios10, launch-screen

I'm having this issue with my app (Swift + Objective C) on devices running iOS 10.3 and up. The app shows the Launch Image, but it doesn't show anything related to the MainStoryboard.

Also, I see some activity in the log, indicating that the other UIViewControllers that are supposed to be shown are in fact alive and active.

The app works fine on devices and emulators running iOS 7/8/9, but there seem to be issues when running on iOS 10 (specifically iOS 10.3 and 10.3.1).

I already checked that the storyboard file is set correctly, and I have a valid entry point (pointing to the UIViewController producing the log messages). It seems like everything is working fine, but the app isn't showing anything but the Launch Image (which is a .xib file, already tried changing it to a storyboard, but it only shows that file as well).

Here are my build settings:

```
buildSettings = {
            ASSETCATALOG_COMPILER_APPICON_NAME = AppIcon;
            CLANG_ENABLE_MODULES = YES;
            CODE_SIGN_IDENTITY = "iPhone Developer";
            "CODE_SIGN_IDENTITY[sdk=iphoneos*]" = "iPhone Developer";
            CURRENT_PROJECT_VERSION = 171;
            ENABLE_BITCODE = NO;
            FRAMEWORK_SEARCH_PATHS = (
                "$(inherited)",
                "$(PROJECT_DIR)",
            );
            GCC_PRECOMPILE_PREFIX_HEADER = YES;
            GCC_PREFIX_HEADER = "Classes/WordpressReader-Prefix.pch";
            INFOPLIST_FILE = "$(SRCROOT)/Info.plist";
            LD_RUNPATH_SEARCH_PATHS = "$(inherited) @executable_path/Frameworks";
            LIBRARY_SEARCH_PATHS = (
                "$(inherited)",
                "$(PROJECT_DIR)/SMI_Mobile_SDK_iOS/SDK",
                "$(PROJECT_DIR)/YuMe",
            );
            PRODUCT_NAME = Project;
            PROVISIONING_PROFILE = "2cf4e4e7-659d-4ffc-80ef-27a946d514f8";
            SWIFT_OBJC_BRIDGING_HEADER = "WordpressReader-Bridging-Header.h";
            SWIFT_OBJC_INTERFACE_HEADER_NAME = "WordpressReader-Swift.h";
            SWIFT_OPTIMIZATION_LEVEL = "-Onone";
            SWIFT_VERSION = 3.0;
            VALIDATE_PRODUCT = YES;
            VALID_ARCHS = "arm64 armv7s armv7";
            VERSIONING_SYSTEM = "apple-generic";
            WRAPPER_EXTENSION = app;
        };
```

Please let me know if you have any idea about this issue. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Show your build settings

Comment: you don't seem like a noob, but just for the sake of being sure, do you have any breakpoints set? breakpoints that only get activated in your iOS 10 related code? And all of this is happening without any errors?!

Comment: @DanielLegler I added some information about my build settings. I don't know if that information is enough, but I'll add more if you need it. Thanks for taking your time to look into this issue of mine.

Comment: @Honey I double-checked to see if I had any break points, but it seems there are none. I'm getting some errors, but nothing that seems related to what's happening (for example, some Google Tag container not being accesible or so). Thanks for taking your time to look into this.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, I couldn't fix this project. I believe what @DanielLegler wrote had a lot of sense. I don't know what changed in iOS 10.3, but it affected all of the apps generated from this project (using different targets). The original project was created using xCode 6.4 or older, so I believe something went wrong while keeping it up to date with the new xCodes. 
The only solution I could think of after trying everything else was to create a new project and recreate this project there, adding all dependencies and source code. It worked, but I'm disappointed I couldn't figure out what was the problem exactly.